# Android Image processing Code Explaination

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am a new programmer.Could you please explain these line of code?

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: did you tried referring developer.android.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty self explanatory, you know.

In the first line of code, first gets the window instance using the activitie's `getWindow()` method. There is an `addFlags(int)` method in the `Window` instance you just got. So you can call

```
getWindow().addFlags(/*blah blah blah*/);
```

What `addFlags` mean is that it adds some special attributes to the window. In this case, it is `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` which is a constant defined in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` class. I think you can get it. **This line of code sets the window to full screen!** Easy, huh?

The second line of code, as the method name suggests, (`setRequestedOrientation`) sets the orientation of the screen to something. And that something is what's in the brackets i.e. `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`. Again `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` is a constant defined in the `ActivityInfo` class. **This line of code just sets the orientation to landscape mode.**

**By the way, this code doesn't process any images at all**

Comment: thanks @Sweeper this ans was  very helpfull for me...I understand it very well.could you please explain these lines also..

Comment: private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "Wallet Lock");

Comment: @Touseef_1 you mean you want me to explain this to you as well? Come on man! This site isn't for explaining code! I helped you once and you want me to do it twice?

Comment: no issue if u donot want to help twice any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above code restricts the orientation of activity from java code. On change of orientation; activity will not be destroyed.

Comment: thanks @GDroid...I got it very well.